# Trace of matrices inequality

Tags: matrices, trace

If I have two matrices, $\mathbf{A}$ which is symmetric and postive definite, and $\mathbf{B}$ symmetric, positive definite, and all entries in $\mathbf{B}$ are between 0 and 1, with the diagonal entries all equal to 1.

I can't seem to see why tr($\mathbf{AB}$) $\leq$ tr($\mathbf{A}$).

Thanks.

Comment: As stated below, this is untrue.  Did you mean to type $ \text{tr}(AB) \leq n \text{tr}(A)$?

Answer (score 8):

Not true.  Try $A = B = \pmatrix{1 & t\cr t & 1\cr}$ for $0 < t < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
{\rm Tr}\pars{AB}
=
\sum_{ij}A_{ij}B_{ji} < \sum_{ij}A_{ij}\quad\mbox{if}\quad A_{ij} > 0, \forall i,j.\
\mbox{So, what ?}
$$

Comment: One has to observe:
$$
\sum_{i,j} A_{ij} \ge \sum_{i} A_{ii} = \operatorname{Tr} (A).
$$